# how to train deep learning network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

There's two things I don't know how to do about them.

1. I trained the network with alexnet, it couldn't converge. And there was no overfiting. However, when I trained the network with lenet, it converged. Why is that?
2. I trained the network to solve a problem. It converged, however not enough. The softmax loss can't be lower(0.2). And how can I deal about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An inability to overfit may be caused by a lack of network capacity or a bug in your code itself. Are you training the model from scratch? Did you write the model yourself? Are you working on a task at a similar scale to Imagenet classification?
2. Plateauing of a loss is to be expecting during any kind of model training. But without any learning curves showing the loss across epochs, a loss of "0.2" is meaningless.

Without knowing the exact task your're working on, the framework you're using, source code, learning curves, and/or any debugging steps you've taken, nobody will be able to really answer your questions. I suggest you go back to the machine learning basics in the [cs231 lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfnWJUyUJYU&list=PLkt2uSq6rBVctENoVBg1TpCC7OQi31AlC) (particularly Lectures 4,5) or [Andrew Ng's Coursera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeHZOdmJvFU&list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A4rycgrgOYma6zxF4BZGGPW) course for a more rudimentary knowledge.

Comment: 1. Yeah there's a bug in my alexnet model.

Comment: 2. Thank you for your advice.